# Optional AttributeGroup

Tags: xsd

I have to define a attribute group for 2 mutually inclusive data elements. In the below example if `TO_DT` is present `FROM_DT` has to be present and `TO_DT` is not present then `FROM_DT` is not present.

I thought of creating these as mandatory attributes and define attributegroup as optional but its not working:

```
<xs:attributeGroup name="DateRangeAttributes" id="Element_Common_545">
  <xs:attribute name="TO_DT" type="xs:date" use="required" id="Element_Common_547"/>
  <xs:attribute name="FROM_DT" type="xs:date" use="required" id="Element_Common_546"/>
<xs:attributeGroup>
```

Can anyone suggest a way to handle this using attributes

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, that kind of constraint can't be enforced by XML Schema (1.0). You'll have a enforce it elsewhere (such as with code or XSLT) or change the format. Possibilities:

- Provide default values so both are effectively always present.
- Use a single attribute containing a length-2 list of dates.
- Use elements (you could also control the order, unlike attributes).

Answer (score 0):

These constraints can be expressed in Schematron and in XML Schema 1.1.